# Modify modal options in SimpleModal (jQuery dialog framework)

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I would like to know if it is possible to change a modal option when I am already showing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You can use javascript (for example with jquery) todo this.

Comment: i already try to do this : jQuery("#monId").modal({close:false});
but is not working.

Comment: html code:
<div id="mydiv">blabla</div>
<span onclick="activeClose()">Active close button</span>


javascript code:
jQuery("#mydiv").modal({close:false});

function activeClose(){
   jQuery("#mydiv").modal({close:true});
}

this is my code, but when you click on the button, the close button doesn't appear.